# WorkManager doWork getting fired twice

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My goal is to run a simple task once an hour. At application start, I register an unique periodic work with `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP` flag.

Here's my implementation:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

    public MyWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
        // I don't do anyting with workerParams
    }

    public static void enqueueWork() {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
                .build();

        PeriodicWorkRequest request = new PeriodicWorkRequest
                .Builder(MyWorker.class, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .addTag("MyWorkerWork")
                .build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("MyWorkerWork",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        Log.i(TAG, "doWork");
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

The only place I call `enqueueWork()` is at `Application#onCreate`.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        MyWorker.enqueueWork();
    }
}
```

Above setup runs somewhat okay. One of the problems is that sometimes `doWork` is called twice in a row, with ~30 sec of time in between. This is not 100% reproducible but I see this often when I leave the phone overnight and come back next day and turn on the phone display for the first time.

Typical log would look like this:

```
01-13 13:29:04.601 19018    19449    I/MyApp: doWork
01-13 13:29:04.700 19018    19124    I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=37064d6c-297b-4c0d-9fd7-xxxxxxxxxxxx, tags={ com.xxx.MyWorker, MyWorkerWork } ] 
01-13 13:29:42.203 19018    19482    I/MyApp: doWork
01-13 13:29:42.292 19018    19145    I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=37064d6c-297b-4c0d-9fd7-xxxxxxxxxxxx, tags={ com.xxx.MyWorker, MyWorkerWork } ]
```

The interesting thing is that this happens WITHOUT process getting killed. If you experienced this before, please help.

Comment: This might not be a solution, but since nobody else had suggestions, it would be worth trying to see what happens if you replace ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP with ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE